# How does recursive function return an int when the base case returns a bool?

Tags: c++, recursion

I have a function that will return the number of subsets that add up to 0.

I am given this solution, but I don't understand why it actually works.

```
int countZeroSumSubsets(Vector<int> &v, int index, int sumSoFar) {
    if (index == v.size()) {
        return (sumSoFar == 0);
    } else {
        return countZeroSumSubsets(v, index + 1, sumSoFar + v[index])
             + countZeroSumSubsets(v, index + 1, sumSoFar);
    }
}
```

I get that it is going through a general inclusion / exclusion pattern, and for each integer in the vector, it is deciding whether to include, or exclude this integer in the subset.  The base case being the end of this vector, and will return whether the sum of that subset is equal to 0 or not.

What I don't understand, is how does the function actually keep track of the number of times the base case returned true (i.e. number of subsets that sum to zero), since it just returns a bool.

To try and understand it further, I coded up my own solution (below) but I still don't quite understand it.

```
int countZeroSumLeonard(Vector<int> &v, int index, int sumSoFar, int& count) {
    // Base case, index = size
    if (index == v.size()) {
        if (sumSoFar == 0) {
            count++;
        }
    } else {
        // include that number in our sum
        countZeroSumLeonard(v, index + 1, sumSoFar + v[index], count);

        // exclude that number from our sum
        countZeroSumLeonard(v, index + 1, sumSoFar, count);
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: `bool` can be implicitly converted to `int` and vice versa

Comment: Okay wow, so simple!! Thank's very much, it all makes sense now :)

Comment: Te function always returns an `int` - `false` implicitly converts to 0, and `true` to 1. The solution is a slightly obfuscated equivalent to `return sumSoFar == 0 ? 1 : 0;`.